# Angle between two curves at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis

> In complex analysis, how would I find the angle between the two curves $f(z)=0$ and $g(z)=0$ at $\infty$?

My guess would be that we would let $w=\frac{1}{z}$ and find the angle between the two curves at $w=0$ but if this is right would it work in every case or are there exceptions?

Comment: $z^{-1}$ is conformal so it should work.

Comment: Perhaps you should take limit of $w$ goes to zero in both parts separately. Not sure if it makes a difference in most cases.